# Joi .custom() validator does not get executed on a not provided field

Tags: javascript, validation, joi

## Requirements

The object has two properties:

- A `number`, let's call it `firstField`
- A `string`, let's call it `secondField`

Now here are the validation requirements

- `firstField` is always `required`
- `secondField` is required when `firstField` is equals `1`. And `forbidden` when `firstField` is not `1`

That could easily get solved with a `.when()`

But actually to find out if the secondField is required, I have to do some checks based on the firstField and a variable in the validation context.

## Current code

```
Joi.object({
    firstField: Joi.number().required(),
    secondField: Joi.custom((value, helpers) => {
        if (firstField === helpers.prefs.context.someValue) {
            // test secondField with forbidden and return error when secondField is provided, otherwise return value
        }
        // test secondField with required and return error when secondField is not provided, otherwise return value
    }),
});
```

Now my problem is, that the custom validator does not get executed when I send in:

```
{
    firstField: "test",
}
```

But I want it to execute

## What I tried

- When I provide `secondField` in the input, the custom validator does get executed
- When I use a `.when()` instead of the custom validator, then the `.when()` does get executed, even when `secondField` is not provided
- So i tried to put a `.when("firstField", { is: Joi.any(), then: Joi.any(), otherwise: Joi.any()})` in front of the custom validator, but still no luck

I really tried around a lot

A last solution I see is to put the custom validator on the parent object of the fields, and in that test the child fields in context of the validation context

What is the best way to solve this? Is it even recommended testing for forbidden/required on the field directly, or should that be done on the parent all the time?

Comment: In the end i changed my whole validation to custom joi. So i wrote custom validators where i had a lot more flexibility. It was worth the time it took to learn to write those in joi and now everything works perfect.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.ref()` to access context values, per the docs:

> **ref(key, [options])**
>
> If a key starts with $ is signifies a context reference which is looked up in the context option object.

Source: https://joi.dev/api/?v=17.7.0#refkey-options

With this you can leverage `when()` to express your condition:

```js
Joi.when("firstField", {
  is: Joi.ref("$someValue"),
  then: Joi.forbidden(),
  otherwise: Joi.string(),
});
```